# How to make Git automatically ignore certain files when I'm staging changes?

Tags: git, staging

I have a folder in my Git directory that stores information about when my program runs and I don't want this information to keep getting added to the repo.

Currently I just avoid selecting files from this folder in the git gui. This can be very cumbersome however as there are often a lot of them. What is the best way to do this either using the gui or the command line?

Comment: You can read more about [gitignore at the docs](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitignore.html).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the .gitignore file, note that you might have to exclude files with

```
 git rm --cached filename
```

from tracking, which were put there before you added the rule for them, see https://help.github.com/articles/ignoring-files

Answer (score 2):

Put the path to that directory into the `.gitignore` file, like this:

```
echo 'ignored-files/' >>.gitignore
```

Put the `.gitignore` file under version control if other developers might want to ignore those files as well.